# Debugging child process spawned by electron in VS code

Tags: node.js, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I am building an electron app in typescript with webpack, and I am running into the following vscode debugging problem:

**Info:** The main process spawns a child process by calling `fork('./dist/child', [], {execArgv: ['--debug-brk=3001']})`. My `launch.json` looks as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Debug child process",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 3001
}
```

**Steps:**

1. I launch my electron app in a terminal
2. hit F5 to launch the vscode debugger

As expected, it hits a break at the first line of my webpack build for the child process code (due to `debug-brk`). This allows me to register additional breakpoints with the debugger in my typescript source.

3. as expected, upon continuing, vscode hits those breakpoints nicely within my ts source. Good.

**Problem:** If I now restart the debugger (without any source changes or registering new breakpoints)...

1. The initial breakpoint in the build is not hit
2. My manually added breakpoints are marked ignored (*Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?).*)
3. Any new breakpoint I add at this point is also marked ignored.

I realize that debugging by Attach is different from debugging by Launch, and that the initial break enforced by a `debug-brk` fork is needed to give one the opportunity to register breakpoints for a node process that is attached to.

**Question:** However, what I would like to improve in my debugging experience is that a simple restart of the debugger is *not enough* to re-register some new (or old) breakpoints. I have to *entirely exit* my app and start it again, *before* the debugger upon restart will again halt at the first line of my build and recognize breakpoints I add at that stage.

Is there a way anybody could recommend to improve this debug experience? I don't mind some extra steps as compared to a Launch debugging session, but having to manually quit and start my app just to debug it is a bit cumbersome, and makes actually debugging in the console almost more preferable...

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for the use case I've actually found a pretty ok way to debug the forked process. I will write it up for future reference of people with similar needs:

I detached development of the child process from the main process. Both only communicate through `process.on('message', handler)` and `child.send(...)`. So basically I make my `process.on` call in the child process conditional on whether I set `process.env.NODE_ENV==='DEBUG'`. Then I made a launch configuration just for the child process, like this

```
{
    "type": "node2",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch child process",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main/child_process/Child.ts",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/dist/child.js"
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "DEBUG"
    },
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Then I can just mock the requests that would come in through `process.on` in a production environment by calling the handler manually with mock messages.